# Get list of nearby places with Google Places API

Tags: ios, google-places

I am working on a project which can fetch the list of nearby places (from my current place). I use Google Places API and what I have tried is shown below. I see new view which has a mapview with mark position of most prominent places and table which contains list of these places. I need to fetch list of the places so that I can render it on my tableview.

```
  - (IBAction)pickPlace:(UIButton *)sender {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5108396, -0.0922251);
  CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001);
  CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001);
  GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast                                                                   coordinate:southWest];
GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
  _placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];

  [_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
      return;
    }

    if (place != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
      NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
      NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"No place selected");
    }
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you shouldn't use `GMSPlacePicker`, because it offers the UI to you for your user to make a single selection. If you want a list of places that you can display yourself then you should use the REST interface provided by google to get the required details and update your UI.

Comment: Are you sure is not possible to get ID all places from mapView and transport to my own UITableView?

Comment: The map view is private, if you did access it you could, but it isn't the right way to solve the problem

Comment: I have API key. It is enough to do access to private data from Google Places API?

Comment: the map view is private - as in the `GMSPlacePicker` doesn't give you access to it, or a list of places if finds...

Answer (score 0):

It is doable to get **list of nearby places** (from my current place) with Google Places API. I used the following method to achieve the same:

```
[GMSPlaceClient currentPlaceWithCallback:]
```

An array of nearby places with likelihood is returned.